# Different content with Apache's DefaultHttpClient and HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http

I want to read the content of a website (http://www.google.com) in an Android app. Using the deprecated DefaultHttpClient still works fine and I always get a content length of about 15.000 characters:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet g = new HttpGet(target);
HttpResponse res = client.execute(g);
InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
return Base64.encodeToString(builder.toString().getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

However, when I use a HttpURLConnection to achieve the same, I get a different content with a length of about 100.000 characters.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(target).openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
return Base64.encodeToString(builder.toString().getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Does anybody know, why there is such a big difference. Thanks!

Comment: What problem you are getting with `HttpURLConnection` ?

Comment: Did you check whether the requests contain the same user agent?

Comment: There are so many JavaScript things loaded when I use the HttpURLConnection which is not the case with the DefaultHttpClient (100.000 characters instead of 15.000)

Comment: Thank you @FD_! The problem was indeed caused by the user agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the user agent. With the following code, the two requests behave the same:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Apache-HttpClient");
```